# Animate the 'backgroundColor' for a UIButton in iOS using Swift3

Tags: ios, swift3, core-animation

I would like to animate the backgroundColor property of my UIButtons but I'm not sure where to begin. I've never used Core Animation, I'm not sure if I even need it for something so basic?

I've styled the buttons using a class and a method that looks something like this:

*redTheme.swift*

```
    func makeRedButton() {    
        self.layer.backgroundColor = myCustomRedcolor  
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it with `UIView Animation` as the following :

**Note**: Simply don't forget to set the background to clear before you perform the animation otherwise it won't work. That's because animation need a starting and ending point, starting point is clear color to Red. Or alpha 0 to alpha 1 or the other way around.

```
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 50, height: 50))
button.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
self.view.addSubview(button)

        func makeRedButton() {

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
                button.layer.backgroundColor =  UIColor.red.cgColor
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 4** - A simple way to animate any change on your `UIButton` or any other `UIView`:

```
UIView.transition(with: button, duration: 0.3, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
  self.button.backgroundColor = .red
  self.button.setTitle("ERROR", for: .normal)
  self.button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
})
```

Comment: set title color doesn't get animated

Answer (score 2):

For some reason animating button.layer.backgroundColor
had zero effect for my custom uibutton hence I animated alpha like so:

```
func provideVisualFeedback(_ sender:UIButton!)
{
    sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.whatever
    sender.alpha = 0
    UIView .animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
        sender.alpha = 1
    }, completion: { completed in
        if completed {
            sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        }
    })
}
```

and then

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender:NumberPadButton!)
{
    provideVisualFeedback(sender)
    do your thing once animation was setup with the helper above
```